# println only some parameters of an array

Tags: java, sockets, object, parameters, println

I have a java socket which sends parameters from the client to the server. i want to be able to only display some of the parameters which get sent, and not all of them. at the moment all of them get displayed via println. For example; on the server side i would only like to display the "age" rather than all the parameters

my client code:

```
ObjectOutputStream oos;
ObjectInputStream ois;
Socket socket;
int[] data = { lotsize, bedrooms, localSchools, age, garages, bathrooms };

try {
    socket = new Socket("127.0.0.1", 8888);
    oos = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
    ois = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
    oos.writeObject(data);
    oos.flush();
    ois.close();
    oos.close();
} catch (IOException e) {
    System.out.println(e.getMessage());
}
```

my server code:

```
while (true) {
    int[] data = (int[])ois.readObject();
    oos.close();
    ois.close();

    for (int d : data)
        System.out.println(d);

    break;
}
```

Comment: Create Map<Key, Value> where key is name of parameter and then you can just take value of key "age"

Comment: Why do you have a `while (true) { .... break; }`? You don't need the while/break here: if you want `{}` to scope the variables, you can just add those.

Comment: @RafałSokalski Can you please provide a snippet of code as i am new to Java and unsure on how to do this

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is a satisfying solution to your request... there isn't any way to differentiate between the integers in your array server-side. What you could do is dedicate a specific index to age e.g. data[3] = age, then simply println(data[3]). If you do go this route, make sure it's documented.

Answer (score 0):

Declare Map and put values. It's just an example I don't know how your data structure should looks like.

```
    Map<String, Integer> data = new HashMap<>();
    data.put("lotsize", 1);
    data.put("bedrooms", 1);
    data.put("localSchools", 1);
    data.put("age", 2);
    data.put("garages", 1);
    data.put("bathrooms", 1);
```

And then write the same way like you have right now and just change reading to:

```
Map<String, Integer> data = (Map<String, Integer>) ois.readObject();
```

And now you can print your age this way:

```
System.out.println(data.get("age"));
```